# Exchange Online Signature for new and replay message

Tags: exchange-server

I try to create a signature in Exchange On-line. This signature have two triggers:

1. Add signature to new e-mail:

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
       <style type="text/css">
         h1 {font-size: 14pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial,sans-serif; color:#F79646;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:normal;}  
         h2 {font-size: 11pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial,sans-serif;margin-bottom:1em;margin-top:0;font-weight:normal;}  
         .email {font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif; color:blue;text-decoration:underline;}  
         p {font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;}  
         .nazwafirmy {font-size:12pt; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif; color:#F79646;}  
         a {text-decoration:underline; color:blue;}  
         .danefirmy {color:#A6A6A6;}  
         .danefirmy b {color:gray; font-weight:normal;}  
         .infoprawne {font-size:8pt; color:#A6A6A6;}  
       </style>  
     </head>
     <body>
       <p>Pozdrawiam,</p>
       <h1>%%displayname%%</h1>
       <h2>%%title%%</h2>
       <p class="email">%%email%%</p>
       <p>%%mobilenumber%%</p>
       <br />
       <p class="nazwafirmy">Company</p>
       <p>ul.<br />tel. / fax:<br /></p>
       <p><a href="http://www.link.pl/">www.link.pl</a></p>
       <br />
       <p class="danefirmy"><b>NIP: </b><br />
         <b>Some information</b><br /><br />
       </p>
       <p class="infoprawne">Some information<br />
         <br />
       </p>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. And the second trigger - added after replay message:

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  >
     <head>
       <style type="text/css">
       p {font-size: 10pt; font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;}
       </style>
     </head>
     <body>
       <p>Pozdrawiam,</p>
       <p>%%displayname%%</p>
       <p>Supremo Sp. z o.o.</p>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

I try to add this signature using rules in Exchange (like that):
http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/Ff852816.aspx#FallbackAction

or

http://www.axon-it.com/2012/02/22/office-365-email-footers/

and

http://www.axon-it.com/2012/01/23/office-365-email-disclaimer/

and even

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/p/48901/171956.aspx#171956

but without any results.

I want to do something like that:

1. Create new e-mail
2. Send new e-mail - the FIRST trigger (add signature) has been activated
3. I receive answer for my first e-mail
4. When I sent a replay e-mail the SECOND trigger has activated (add only replay signature)

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create two other rules:
1. activate when send new email - except when subject start: RE, FWD, ODP.
2. activate when subject email was RE, FED, ODP.

At now, everything is working :)